# How can I verify account (say, Apple ID) user entered in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I wrote an app for Android which uses Google account registered in phone. App lists account and let user pick one for user id. Reasons for this are:

- No need to ask password.
- I want unique user id. Other can't use someone-else's id without knowing it's password.
- User id should be human readable. So Google account is very suitable.

This scheme works very well in Android. And now I'm investigating how can I do similar thing in iPhone.

First I searched the way to list Apple ID in iPhone. I learned it's impossible in iOS shortly. Now I want to know how can I verity some account (Apple ID will be fine) user entered.

Use case for this is like:

- Run app.
- App asks user to enter Apple ID, but no password.
- App verifies that Apple ID is valid and use that as user id, sending that to server.
- The other user can communicate by referencing that id.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s no support in iOS for using Apple ID to authenticate the user in your own apps.

In iOS 6, you can use Facebook and Twitter (and in China, Sina Weibo) with [Accounts.framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Accounts/Reference/AccountsFrameworkRef/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I need to think about alternative way.

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't offer an accessible SDK to interact with Apple IDs. At least to the best of my knowledge.
I don't think you are going to be able to replicate the functionality that you have on Android in iOS.